# how to create my own map using another function i defined in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to create map using another function that I have been supplied with can anyone help so

I have created:

```
ConcatListsOnFunc :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
ConcatListsOnFuncf []     = []
ConcatListsOnFunc func (y:ys) = func y ++ flattenMap func ys
```

and i was wondering how i can use that function above to implement the higher order function `map`

which is of type

```
myMap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

`from myMap with input (+1) [1,2,3] should give output [2,3,4]`

can anyone help is there a way to create myMap using my previously defined function with a lambda function?

Comment: What's the difference between `concatListsOnFunc` and `flattenMap`?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap items in a singleton list, so:

```
myMap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
myMap f = concatListsOfFunc (\x -> [f x])
```